# TSQL Synoym for a database name

Tags: t-sql

I have many stored procedures in a sql server database [A] that need to refer to tables in another database [B] in the same server.

So in a typical sp I amy have statements like

```
  select * from [A].table1 inner join
                [B].table2 .....
```

This works well .However the [B] database name may change sometime in future .So I would like to make that a variable (A synonym to another database) . One approach would of course be to create synonyms to tables in [B] in database [A].  Also I am not wanting to use dynamic sql.

Other databases (ex Oracle) have concepts like database links which is a symberolic name to any other database (maybe on another server)

Wondering if any equivalent feature available in TSQL

Thanks

Comment: [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)  More appropriate for DBA forum though.  Not positive you can create a link to the same server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not have database synonyms. Your only option is to create synonyms for all required objects from [B] in [A]. You can however create a procedure that automatically loops through the objects in [B] and creates their synonyms in [A].